# maven-compiler-plugin broken on linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven

I have a maven project. In the `pom.xml` file the following is stated:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

AFAIK this is correct, it should build against `JDK 7`.

I run a Debian based Linux dist and when I do `mvn clean install` it seems to always build against the javac version I have set in my os.

I've tried reading up on what the plugin exactly does https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/, but it doesn't really state how.

An example is I have `javac 8` running on my os. When I invoke `mvn clean install`, the project compiles against `JDK 8` and not `JDK 7` as stated in the `pom.xml`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the maven-compiler-plugin uses %JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac to compile, unless:

- you set the executable-parameter to a different location
- you use [Toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html), which seems to match your requirements, i.e a different Java Runtime for Maven compared to the JDK for the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: Ah thanks. I think I misunderstood what source and target actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Source and target settings are just passed to the javac compiler as parameters. The javac installed on the machine is used.

Comment: I have multiple javac's installed also. Then what is the purpose of the plugin other than just stating what version javac should be using?

Comment: A Java 8 may compile sources in java 7 format and generate classes of java 7 format. To some degree this works fine.